# How to duplicate remote branch in Git without checkout?

Tags: git

Is it possible, in Git, to duplicate remote branch in the way that do not change local files? If not, what are the minimal changes that must be done to achieve this?

By saying do not change local files I mean do not change them at all during the whole process. Stashing them and bringing back later is treated as a change. Checkout obviously is changing local files, they will change to reflect the state of the branch you are checking out.

Example, branches before:

- origin/master (at commit1)
- master (at commit2, some loose files as well)

Branches after:

- origin/master (at commit1)
- origin/master-copy (at commit1)
- master (no changed at any step during process, still at commit2, the same loose files as above)

Comment: A Git branch is just a pointer to a commit. [Branch creation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [pushing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) doesn't require checkout.

Comment: I tried to answer, but I'm not sure you don't made any typo (`origin/master` and `origin/master-copy` at the same commit?)

Comment: The same. That's why I called it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is to simply create a remote branch pointing to commit 1.

**Short answer**

```
git push origin [commit1 hash]:refs/heads/master-copy
```

**Long answer**

Lets say this is you repository:

```
commit 2 (65bc341)   O  <-- master
                     |
     (more commits) ...
                     |
commit 1 (125afe4)   O  <-- origin/master
```

To achive what you want you use the git push command, you don't need to create a local branch. You need to pass three parameters to the push command:

```
git push [REMOTE NAME] [WHERE SHOULD THE REMOTE BRANCH POINT TO]:[REMOTE BRANCH NAME]
```

Assumming you are following standard names, REMOTE NAME willl probably be "origin".

The REMOTE BRANCH NAME is master-copy.

And finally, WHERE SHOULD THE REMOTE BRANCH POINT TO is the hash of the commit1 (125afe4 in the example I used above)

...so the command would be:

```
git push origin 125afe4:master-copy
```

Whith this command you are telling git that in the remote named "origin" you want to create a new branch named "master-copy" pointing to commit 125afe4.

If you run this command (and you did not create any local branch called master-copy) you will get this error

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master-copy
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@WHATEREVER_YOUR_REPO_URL_IS'
```

Why you get this response? Because git doesn´t know if you are trying to create a branch or a tag in the remote repository. To resolve the ambiguity you run

```
    git push origin 125afe4:refs/heads/master-copy
```

et voila!

```
commit 2 (65bc341)   O  <-- master
                     |
     (more commits) ...
                     |
commit 1 (125afe4)   O  <-- origin/master origin/master-copy
```

If you follow the steps in the accepted answer, the local branch "master-copy" that you create and later delete is the one that resolves the ambiguity. I hope I could provide you with some insights about how `git-push` works and show you that you don't really need this local branch. You can get what you need with one command instead of three!

Remember, if you want to remove the remote branch later you can run

```
git push --delete origin master-copy
```

or you can use the older syntax

```
git push origin :master-copy
```

Answer (score 11):

The `git branch` command will let you create a new branch without needing to do any checking out or changes to local files.  Then you would need to push the new remote branch.

The specific steps that you would need to do:

1. `git branch master-copy origin/master` -- Create a local copy of the branch that you will make into a new remote
2. `git push origin master-copy` -- Push the local branch to the remote
3. `git branch -D master-copy` -- Delete the local branch copy

All of this is done without doing any checkout of files.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explaination. I've always wondered what the ":refs/heads/" part was about. This finally fills in a blank spot in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

.1 Get local copy of `origin/master` at commit 1

```
 git checkout -b master-copy master
```

.2 Push this new branch to origin

```
 git push origin master-copy
```

.3 Update `origin/master` at commit 1

```
 git push origin master-copy:master -f
```

.4 Remove local `master-copy`

```
 git branch -D master-copy
```

Comment: Checkout means change in local directory.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal

1. `git clone "your repository link"`
2. `cd "master's project routes"`
3. `git branch master-copy`
4. `git checkout master-copy`
5. `git push origin master-copy`

After that you will have a copy of your master project in a new branch "master-copy". If you wants to merge it  with your master branch in the future. I recommend you to use feature/master-copy instead of master-copy.

Comment: Checkout means change in local directory.

Comment: @waste Yes, but changes will be done in feature/master-copy, not master-copy. And if you do step number five the new feature will appear in remote branch.